# P-adic Lie groups - Representation theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I am quite familiar with the Representation Theory for locally compact groups and nilpotent Lie groups. I want to start with the study of $p$-adic Lie groups representation theory, in particular Matrix groups.

Can someone give some good (self-contained) reference?